# Dynamic Calculation in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need calculation with selected timefilter value.

I added some static calculation "scripted fields" management > index patterns.
But but it should change according to selected day count.

```
return (totalAmount/selectedDay);
```

For example;
if today selected in time filter. *selectedDay* should be 1;
or weekly selection, should be day in week.

Does it possible or need another trick to calculate this?

Comment: A scripted-field can only operate on whatever is available in a given document. A scripted-field doesn't have access to context data, such as the time picker bounds or duration.

Comment: ok thanks. Is there any way to access context data to such a calculation?

Comment: Not in the Discover view

Comment: In fact i need this in visualition. i will add this calculated value to pie/donut chart

Comment: @Val what about showing in visualization screen ?
for e.g. sum(field)/now-1d